# Clipped Layer - attribute table empty

Tags: arcgis-pro, clip

Using ArcGIS Pro - I clipped a city wide parcel layer using a polygon feature layer I created in order to limit the context around my site.   The clipped parcel layer attribute table is empty.

Why is the clipped feature layer losing this data?

Comment: Always make sure to Repair Geometry before attempting geometric intersection.

Comment: In addition the geometry problem Vince covers, if the polygon layer you created has no coordinate system properly defined, when you run the clip the result would be empty because there is no actual overlay.

Comment: Interesting.  Will double check that.  Thank you.

Comment: The Clipping Polygon did not have a CRS assigned.   I assigned one and the process was successful.